# Is $ [\Bbb Q(\pi):\Bbb Q]$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Is the extension field  $ [\Bbb Q(\pi):\Bbb Q]$  finite?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The element $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if the simple extension  $F(\alpha)/F$ is finite

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$\pi$ is transcendental.